# Different Bindings for single custom ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, uwp

I've defined this ControlTemplate

```xaml
<Page>
    <Page.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="Test">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Example"></TextBlock>
                <CheckBox  IsChecked="True"></CheckBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource Test}"> </ContentControl><!-- Text here should be Status.AlertText and IsChecked should be two-way binding for Status.AlertChecked -->
        <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource Test}"></ContentControl> <!-- Text here should be Status.FocusText and IsChecked should be two-way binding for Status.FocusChecked -->
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

several times in the same Page. Each time the text in "Example" will be binded to a different text, and the Checkbox "IsChecked" will be a two-way binding to a boolean property.

How can I bind this properly?

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public Status Status { get; set; } = new Status();
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = Reporte;
        }
    }

public class Reporte :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool FocusChecked { get; set; }
    public string FocusText { get; set; }
    public bool AlertChecked { get; set; }
    public string AlertText  { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You could just bind it directly to the datacontext (`{Binding Path=.}`) and swap out the datacontext. (Or write your own UserControl that has a property like the ListBox's `DisplayMemberName`)

Comment: I use a single DataContext for the whole Page and the controls will be bound to different properties of the DataContext. What should I bind, the ControlTemplate or the ContentControl?

Comment: Depends on how you use it. Could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: haven't I already? I edited it anyway. Don't know what else to add really.

Comment: Oh, that simple Ok. Should be easy with a custom control, I'll post that in a minute (or so)

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, why don't you just put the text *inside* of the Checkbox. I don't see the need for a ContentControl to be honest. Is it because you want the CheckBox below the text instead of the left? (`<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding FocusChecked}" Content="{Binding FocusText}"/>`)

Comment: just for reusability (and learning new things). This page might have 15 of this controls one below the other and I wanted to learn if there is a better way than just repeat the code inside the ControlTemplate (because only the Text and the IsChecked will change). In this example it might be an overkill but might become more complex and I want to know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only use properties that a regular CheckBox already has, I suggest you write a ControlTemplate for CheckBoxes:

```xaml
<ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalCheckBox" TargetType="CheckBox">
    <StackPanel>
        <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

You could simply use them this way:

```xaml
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding FocusChecked}" Content="{Binding FocusText}" Template="{StaticResource VerticalCheckBox}"/>
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding AlertChecked}" Content="{Binding AlertText}" Template="{StaticResource VerticalCheckBox}"/>
```

---

If you have more and more properties, you could of course write your own UserControl, e.g. like this:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp7
{
    public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "IsChecked", typeof(bool?), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool?)));

        public bool? IsChecked
        {
            get { return (bool?) GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Text", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string) GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        public MyUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

```xaml
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp7.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp7"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyUserControl}}, Path=Text}"/>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyUserControl}}, Path=IsChecked}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Or even a custom `Control`, with a default style and template, but that is a bit more advanced.

Comment: `Checked` should of course have been `IsChecked`, that was a typo.